# What is the fastest do array padding of the image array

Tags: c, algorithm, padding

So I have an image array in 1D:

```
a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

What is the fastest way to do array padding to surround it with zeoes to have:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3 0
0 4 5 6 0
0 7 8 9 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

I have already declared the b array(which is the padding array of a):

```
float *b = calloc(((data_size_X + 2)*(data_size_Y +2)), sizeof(float));
```

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that a simple set of for loops wouldn't be fast enough here?

Comment: but the image array can be as big as mega pixel ...

Comment: Have you tried the naive version, profiled it, and found that it's too slow? A megapixel isn't very large these days considering processor speeds and RAM, and unless you're doing this in a tight loop I'd be surprised if it were unbelievably slow.

Comment: The only thing that might be slightly faster (because of internal optimizations) would be to use `memcpy` one row at a time. It copies larger chunks of data in one operation (long ints instead of bytes), leveraging the architecture of your hardware. Profile it and you will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some benchmarking. My hunch was right - using `memcpy` is significantly faster than alternatives:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  char* original;
  char* padded;
  long int n, m, ii, jj, kk;
  time_t startT, stopT;

  char *p1, *o1; //  point to first element in row for padded, original

  // pick a reasonably sized image:
  n = 3000;
  m = 2000;

  // allocate memory:
  original = malloc(m * n * sizeof(char));
  padded = calloc((m+2)*(n+2), sizeof(char));

  // put some random values in it:
  for(ii = 0; ii < n*m; ii++) {
    original[ii] = rand()%256;
  }

  // first attempt: completely naive loop
  startT = clock();
  for(kk = 0; kk < 100; kk++) {
    for(ii = 0; ii < m; ii++) {
      for(jj = 0; jj < n; jj++) {
        padded[(ii + 1) * (n + 2) + jj + 1] = original[ ii * n + jj];
      }
    }
  }
  stopT = clock();
  printf("100 loops of 'really slow' took %.3f ms\n", (stopT - startT) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  // second attempt - pre-compute the index offset
  startT = clock();
  for(kk = 0; kk < 100; kk++) {
    for(ii = 0; ii < m; ii++) {
      p1 = padded + (ii + 1) * (n + 2) + 1;
      o1 = original + ii * n;
      for(jj = 0; jj < n; jj++) {
        p1[jj] = o1[jj];
      }
    }
  }
  stopT = clock();
  printf("100 loops of 'not so fast' took %.3f ms\n", (stopT - startT) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  // third attempt: use memcpy to speed up the process    
  startT = clock();
  for(kk = 0; kk < 100; kk++) {
    for(ii = 0; ii < m; ii++) {
      p1 = padded + (ii + 1) * (n + 2) + 1;
      o1 = original + ii * n;
      memcpy(p1, o1, n);
    }
   }
  stopT = clock();
  printf("100 loops of 'fast' took %.3f ms\n", (stopT - startT) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  free(original);
  free(padded);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the resulting output:

```
100 loops of 'really slow' took 3020.585 ms
100 loops of 'not so fast' took 3725.056 ms
100 loops of 'fast' took 332.298 ms
```

When I turned on compiler optimization with `-O3`, the timing changed as follows:

```
100 loops of 'really slow' took 2727.442 ms
100 loops of 'not so fast' took 488.244 ms
100 loops of 'fast' took 326.998 ms
```

Clearly, the compiler "spotted" the cleaner copy loop and tried to optimize it somewhat - but it still didn't do as well as `memcpy`. And there was virtually nothing left to optimize in memcpy.

Comment: I also implement the blocksize when copying the array over, that's a little bit faster

Answer (score 0):

If you've already allocated `b` as you described, the following would probably be faster than nested for-loops:

```
int aIndex;
int maxA = data_size_X * data_size_Y;
float * pb = b + data_size_X + 3;
memset(b, 0, (data_size_X + 2) * (data_size_Y + 2) * sizeof(float));
for (aIndex = 0; aIndex < maxA;  aIndex += data_sizeX) {
    memcpy(pb, a + aIndex, data_size_X);
    pb += (data_size_X + 2);
}
```

Comment: @Floris wow.  and you are a much faster coder than me too!  good answer - uprated.

Comment: just to clarify, doing member is not as fast as doing calloc, right? Because when we calloc we also zero out the whole array, and make that array local.